# Photoshop Scripting: How to know the part of the text that has overflowed

Tags: javascript, text, photoshop-script

I want to spread a long text between multiple slides since it can't be fitted in one.

I do this manually by looking where the text stops in one slide and resume it from there in one next slide (until the entire text has been printed).

Is there a way to automate this procedure? Maybe a method to retrieve the parte of the text *actually* displayed?

Comment: Not sure this could be automated, because PS doesn't know what is 'visible' text... (And you probably should've used Indesign and not Photoshop for this)

Comment: The only way I think you can do this is to loop over your string, character by character. If it fits within the width of the image, go on to the next character. Photoshop doesn't hold any font width or spacing information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be what you want, but it's a start.

It creates a line of text that can within an image. For my example I used a new document that was 640 x 480 @72dpi.

```
// Switch off any dialog boxes
displayDialogs = DialogModes.ERROR; // OFF 

// call the source document
var srcDoc = app.activeDocument;

var myString = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

var w = srcDoc.width.value;
var h = srcDoc.height.value;

var maxWidth = w-20;
var remanderText = "";

for (i = myString.length; i > 0; i--)
{
  var text = myString.slice(0, i);
  create_text("Arial", 36.0, text, 320, 230, "c", maxWidth);

  var sb = get_selection_bounds();

  if (sb[0] < maxWidth)
  {
    //ok
    remanderText = myString.slice(i, myString.length);
    break;
  }
  else
  {
    // delete layer
    srcDoc.activeLayer.remove();
  }
}
alert(remanderText);



// function CREATE TEXT(typeface, size, R, G, B, text content, text X pos, text Y pos)
// --------------------------------------------------------
function create_text(fface, size, content, tX, tY, just, maxw)
{
  var line = content.split("\n");

  // Thanks to visioN for the regex help
  // replaces \n with \r carriage return
  content = content.replace(/\n|<br\s*\/?>/gi, "\r");


// Add a new layer in the new document
  var artLayerRef = app.activeDocument.artLayers.add();

  // Specify that the layer is a text layer
  artLayerRef.kind = LayerKind.TEXT;

  artLayerRef.name = "text";

  //This section defines the color of the hello world text
  textColor = new SolidColor();
  textColor.rgb.red = 0;
  textColor.rgb.green = 0;
  textColor.rgb.blue = 0;

  //Get a reference to the text item so that we can add the text and format it a bit
  textItemRef = artLayerRef.textItem
  textItemRef.font = fface;
  textItemRef.contents = content;
  textItemRef.color = textColor;
  textItemRef.size = size
  textItemRef.position = new Array(tX, tY) //pixels from the left, pixels from the top


  if (just == "CENTRE" || just == "CENTER" || just = "C" || just = "c") just = Justification.CENTER
  else if (just == "RIGHT" || just == "right" || just = "R" || just = "r") just = Justification.RIGHT
  else if (just == "LEFT" || just == "left" || just = "L" || just = "l") just = Justification.LEFT
  else (just = Justification.LEFT);

  activeDocument.activeLayer.textItem.justification = just;
}

// function GET SELECTION BOUNDS ()
// ----------------------------------------------------------------
function get_selection_bounds()
{
  select_layer_as_selection();

  var x = parseFloat(app.activeDocument.selection.bounds[0]);
  var y = parseFloat(app.activeDocument.selection.bounds[1]);
  var x1 = parseFloat(app.activeDocument.selection.bounds[2]);
  var y1 = parseFloat(app.activeDocument.selection.bounds[3]);

  var selW = parseFloat(x1-x);
  var selH = parseFloat(y1-y);

  // select nothing; Deselect all
  app.activeDocument.selection.deselect();

  // return the results as an array
  return [(selW), (selW)];
}


// function SELECT LAYER AS SELECTION()
// --------------------------------------------------------
function select_layer_as_selection()
{
    var id1268 = charIDToTypeID( "setd" );
    var desc307 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var id1269 = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
    var ref257 = new ActionReference();
    var id1270 = charIDToTypeID( "Chnl" );
    var id1271 = charIDToTypeID( "fsel" );
    ref257.putProperty( id1270, id1271 );
    desc307.putReference( id1269, ref257 );
    var id1272 = charIDToTypeID( "T   " );
    var ref258 = new ActionReference();
    var id1273 = charIDToTypeID( "Chnl" );
    var id1274 = charIDToTypeID( "Chnl" );
    var id1275 = charIDToTypeID( "Trsp" );
    ref258.putEnumerated( id1273, id1274, id1275 );
    desc307.putReference( id1272, ref258 );
    executeAction( id1268, desc307, DialogModes.NO )
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's better than nothing, probably the major concern is the speed but of course it has to create and render a new text layer on each iteration. With a binary search it should be faster! Do you think that by peeking at the process in memory we can get something useful? I took a quick look with [HxD](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) but the text appears always in its entirety. (For the record, part of the code are also visible even with their comment)